# I want to "Copy Website" in Visual Studio to a subfolder on the remote site

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment

Trying out this "Copy Website" feature in Visual Studio.

On my remote site the actual IIS application is in a subfolder of the root.

When I go into Copy Website it will only allow me to copy the website directly into the root of the remote site.

Is there a way to tell it to copy the website into this subfolder on the remote site?  If I go into the subfolder on the remote site it tries to find the same subfolder on the local side and gives me a "this folder doesn't exist" message.

This seems like it should be fairly simple functionality and I'm surprised it's not more obvious.  Thanks for any help!  I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the subdirectory to automatically start with in the FTP connection options for the remote site and it will then allow you to copy the website inside this directory.

However, this only worked 2 out of the 4 times I've tried it.  The other 2 times I received a "this folder doesn't exist" (on the local machine) error.  Not sure what's up with that.  The Copy Website tool seems a bit undercooked?

Edit: Ah, I see.  This only works if you're starting a fresh instance of the Copy Website tool.  If you already had the tool up and start a new connection you'll still get the "this folder doesn't exist" message.